# If $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$, $x \leq D$, and $0 \leq 1/(1+x) - 1/(1+y) \leq C$, then is there an upper bound on the value of $y - x$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> If $x \geq 0$, $y \geq 0$, $x \leq D$ and $0 \leq 1/(1+x) - 1/(1+y) \leq C$, then is there an upper bound on the value of $y - x$?

Trying to work this out, am stuck. Not a homework problem.

The larger goal of this is that I'm trying to find some way to convert Euclidean distance to similarity in a way such that there is an upper bound on the difference between the Euclidean distance of two elements (from a fixed point) if we know the upper bound on the difference between their similarities.

Here I'm trying out Similarity = 1/(1 + Distance).

Comment: Pick an $x$. For what values of $y$ have you $0 \leqslant \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1+y} \leqslant C$?

Comment: If $C\cdot(1+D)<1$ then $$y-x\leqslant\frac{C\cdot(1+D)^2}{1-C\cdot(1+D)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Note that the sequence $a_n=\frac1{1+n}$ converges and therefore it is a Cauchy sequence. Then, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_p-a_q|<\epsilon$ for every $p,q\ge N$.